# Finding proprieties of accumulator in JS

Tags: javascript

I am running this accumulator, it works great but I find it challenging to add some proprities in the same object :

```
  let expenseCategories = expenseObj.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    let category = obj['category'];
    // let amount = obj['amount'];
    if (category in acc) {
      acc[category] += 1;
    } else {
      acc[category] = 1;
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
```

> {Transportation: 2, Food: 1, Clothes: 1, Bills: 2, Fun: 1, …}

My initial object also contains a transaction amount

```
{amount: 10, category: "Transportation", date: 20190510, expense: true, ...
{amount: 20, category: "Drinks", date: 20190510, expense: true, ...
{amount: 30, category: "Bills", date: 20190510, expense: true, ...
{amount: 40, category: "Bills", date: 20190510, expense: true, ...
```

My goal here is to calculate sum of each categories like `bills` in the example above would be 70.

I am looking to add this info to display some chart, the expected array looks something like that :

```
0: {name: "Transportation", value: 2, total: 123}
1: {name: "Food", value: 1, total: 456}
2: {name: "Clothes", value: 1, total: 789}
```

This is my attempt with the correct data I already have:

```
let outExpense = Object.entries(expenseCategories).map(([name, value]) => ({ name, value }));
```

This should be dynamic because I don't know categories prior to running code. These are user inputs. Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are counting the occurrences of each `category`. You need to change your implementation a little bit. Instead of creating a number as value, you can create the object you need in the output array as value. Then, simply use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) on the accumulator object to get the array of grouped values

```js
const expenseObj = [{amount: 10, category: "Transportation", date: 20190510, expense: true},
{amount: 20, category: "Drinks", date: 20190510, expense: true},
{amount: 30, category: "Bills", date: 20190510, expense: true},
{amount: 40, category: "Bills", date: 20190510, expense: true}]

let groupCategories = expenseObj.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  let { category, amount } = obj;
  
  if (category in acc) {
    acc[category].value++;    
    acc[category].total += amount;
  } else {
    acc[category] = { name: category, value: 1, total: amount };
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(groupCategories))
```

This is how the accumulator would look like after the changes. If the current object's `category` already exists in the accumulator, increment the `value` and `total`. Else, add the `category` as key and a new object as it's value

```
{
  "Transportation": {
    "name": "Transportation",
    "value": 1,
    "total": 10
  },
  "Drinks": {
    "name": "Drinks",
    "value": 1,
    "total": 20
  },
  "Bills": {
    "name": "Bills",
    "value": 2,
    "total": 70
  }
}
```